# how to cross compile python packages (e.g. Numpy) for ARM

Tags: python, linux, numpy, arm, cross-compiling

I know this question have been posted before. But I couldn't find a complete answer on how to do it.

I would like to use python packages with C extensions such as Numpy and Twisted in an embedded system (platform architecture: ARM 32Bit and some Linux distribution).

Info: the tool chain is already configured.

Found this alternatives:

- Using dockers
- Using distutilscross (sounds the easiest, but couldn't find documentation)

  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distutilscross
- Using VM

Thank you in advance

Comment: Docker does not change the architecture. What runs in the container should also run outside. The same applies to VMs (in contracts to emulators).

Comment: @KlausD. thank you for the comment. Could you give me some step through advices on how to cross compiler in either way?

Comment: Why do you need to cross compile? You can just use packages like Numpy and Twisted on embedded Linux distributions like Raspbian and Armbian. You can install packages using `pip` as you would on a non-embedded system. If needed, you can install Docker on the operating system, run a Python image, and install and run pip packages inside of the container.

Answer (score 1):

[Crossenv](https://pypi.org/project/crossenv/)

But I get the issues with multiarray among working with numpy all the time.

1. Numpy dependable cross compilations are failing with the issue. So I modified PATH to make them start building.
2. Built numpy also fires the issue when imported in target python.

For the second issue:

```
$ sudo apt install python-numpy
```

is meant to be the solution but since I am developing for an embedded system I cannot/have never tried to use it.

I get to a conclusion that I should cross compile it by myself but then a lot more dependency issues occurred. However, one can try it if the target is not a minimalist linux and apt is available.